# Is there a way to show SpriteKit elements on top of UIKit elements?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, uikit

I have created a background view using the instance of `UIImageView`, on top of this `UIKit` element I want to show `SKSpriteNode's` instance which is a `Sprite Kit` element. Whenever I do so, the `Sprite Kit` elements are not visible.

Is there any way to achieve the above mentioned hierarchy?

Answer (score 0):

You need to place a view of type `SKView` on top of the `UIImageView` and establish an `SKScene` inside this view.  Then in the `SKScene`, you can add any sprite or node you want,  just make sure that the view has a background color of transparent, and that the `SKView` has `allowsTransparency` set to true, with the background color of SKScene being transparent as well.